# How to uninstall updates - windows 8.1 is not booting

Tags: windows, boot, uninstall

I need help with my Windows 8.1 Booting. After downloading updates and starting system it showed a message "we couldn't complete the updates. And it started to uninstall, and the screen were freezed, so i restarted and tried to start system recovery, and it was on final step and also showed error. Then I was trying through CMD but I am not sure what to do.

Comment: I am not sure (short of backing up and installing again). Download the Windows 8.1 ISO from Microsoft Downloads. Burn to DVD or bootable USB Key. Start with this and see if Windows 8.1 will install this way and repair the problem

Comment: Hello there and welcome to superuser. Could you please share your system info? Is it a laptop, tablet, etc? Try posting as much info as possible so people can help you better.

Comment: It could be a failing hard drive.

Comment: Since Windows 8.1 reached the "end of Mainstream Support on January 9, 2018," (https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/18581/lifecycle-faq-windows-products) why bother to reinstall it? Update to 10 and/or try another OS, such as Linux.

Comment: "also showed error." - What error?  Edit your question instead of submitting a temporary comment.